# Проблема с настройкой windows 2003

Tags: windows, squid

Никогда не подумал бы, что буду задавать такие вопросы, но все же пришлось.Начну с небольшой предыстории.Решил поднабраться опыта и пошел на одну фирму системным администратором.Там мне дали задание "поднять" сервер с блокировкой по сайтам. В принципе, ничего сложного нет.Поставить windowds server 2003+squid.В чем вообще проблема: не могу раздать интернет в локальную сеть так,чтобы сквид отслеживал все ip.DHCP,Squid,DNS уже настроил,все работает,а вот интернет раздать не могу.Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: а как предполагается "раздать интернет"? (нужно ваше видение задачи)

Comment: windows и squid, это как обезьяна с гранатой.

Comment: я сам такое делал году в 2006, но когда стали кончаться tcp-порты я передумал использовать эту схему )) но всё же, если человек хочет получить такой опыт...

Comment: А мне без разницы как будет раздаваться интернет.И если б я знал варианты,то скорее всего этого вопроса бы здесь не было

Comment: так.. вариант 1. на клиентах прописать в качестве прокси сервера адрес вашего "windowds server 2003+squid".Что в этом случае происходит?

Comment: Нужно раздать...Раздать так, чтобы еще и контролировать squid'ом

Comment: так.. вариант 1. на клиентах прописать в качестве прокси сервера ip-адрес вашего "windowds server 2003+squid" сервера.Что в этом случае происходит? - получение айпи и днс идет по dhcp,айпишк получает прекрасно,но инета нету

Comment: "прописать", означает указать вручную, допустим, в браузере.

Comment: А как-то автоматизовать этот процесс?Там просто 65 машин.И может чтобы не флудить будем писаться в ЛС?Это ускорит процесс.Контакт,почта или скайп.Что Вам удобней?

Answer (score 1):

Если все должно контролироваться Squid, то кальмар должен быть настроен как прозрачный прокси. Т.е. без прописывания на каждой из воркстэйшн-машин.
А просто, не через Кальмара, инет раздается на остальные машины?
Все дело в том, что инет понятие растяжимое: если без участия кальмара инет есть - то все ОК. Нет - добиваемся чтобы был. В частности, прописываем маршруты из одной подсети в другую (между Вашими сетевыми картами на сервере). После этого занимаемся допиливанием кальмара. Пусть он у Вас слушает 80 порт адреса 192.168.10.1 (локалка) и переводит на 192.168.1.1 (подсеть роутера).
Остальные порты можно заблокировать.

Comment: Кальмар пока не стоит.А вот как добиться,чтобы он был?Через RRAS.И как мне проверить, работает  ли передача ДНС на клиентскую машину?Вот ДНСР я могу проверить.

Comment: "В частности, прописываем маршруты из одной подсети в другую (между Вашими сетевыми картами на сервере)" - в настройках tcp?

Comment: Так, дак что мне делать?

Comment: >И как мне проверить, работает ли передача ДНС на клиентскую машину?Проверить настройки соединения на клиенте: "состояние соединения", вкладка "поддержка" кнопка "Подробности" (так в ХР). Там будет указан DNS. В настройках соединения получение IP и DNS должны быть в автомате. Проверка: запустить броузер и перейти куда-либо (только после прописывания маршрутов).  >"маршруты из одной подсети в другую" - в настройках tcp?  Используется команда route. См. справку по ней (набрать в командной строке route ?).Извините, что долго не отвечал